# “Add to Homescreen” within the Android For Work framework

Tags: progressive-web-apps, android-for-work

I do have a PWA where "Add to Homescreen" works fine on Safari for iOS and Chrome for Android.

When I try to deploy the same PWA within the Android For Work framework, deployed on Managed Android devices in my compagny, pop-up appears, but nothing happens...

Does anyone have already succeeded in having this feature work under Android For Work?
If yes, could you share how you achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should provide the results of your efforts, what have you tried so far? can you post the code?

Comment: Well, here is what I tried: launch Chrome > go to [link](https://guitar-tuner.appspot.com/) (this is just a random exemple) > hit the "add a bookmark to home screen button" > check result. Works fine with Chrome. Does work at all using Chrome for Work...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for what is worth, I've found the answer to my issue.
Fact is that it is related to Samsung Touchwiz interface, that prevents this feature to work properly.
It's ok on a stock Android, or even Moto G5, from Android 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Recently Google introduced that ability in Android enterprise to create proper apps from web apps.  It will depend on your solution provider whether this is already supported for your environment.  But you can do a web search for e.g. `android enterprise web apps` to learn more about this.

With that approach the enterprise admin creates the app and can install it on all devices they wish.  At the same time, the app will appear in the work store, so users can just install it like a normal app.

Comment: Yes, I've been informed by our MDM provider that this functionality was available.
And indeed, it's working pretty fine.